# Subplotting both grouped and stacked bar together with plot_ly?

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart, r-plotly

I'm trying to make an interactive side-by-side bar chart where one shows the grouped one and the other shows the percentage.

```
library(plotly)


Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)
#Stacked bar
fig1 <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo')
fig1 <- fig1 %>% add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo')
fig1 <- fig1 %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'stack')

#Group
fig2 <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo')
fig2 <- fig2 %>% add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo')
fig2 <- fig2 %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')
subplot(fig1, fig2)
```

Individually they work, but when I use subplot, either all of the bars seemed to go to 'grouped' version or they go to 'stacked' like so:[image]

Are there any fixes for this? I'm not even sure why the code is no working.

Comment: Do you need one legend for the resulted graph? Or we can group with separate legends for every plot?

Comment: It would be best if I can get one legend for the whole graph as the share the same data set. Or I'm also looking into getting separate legends for each plots but I just don't know how to change the location (Ie have the respective legends underneath each plot such as blue/yellow for first plot, green/red for second plot)

Comment: I don't know how to make one legend for both graphs. I can offer the solution with separate legends. If you need it - I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the legend isn't going to let you have a stacked and dodged bar chart in the same `subplot`. One of the limitations of `subplot` is that there is only one layout. That means there can be only one `barmode`. There are still a lot of different ways that you could should these two plots side by side, though.

By the way, you wrote that one of the two was percentages, but neither plot is set that way.

Here is one way you can make this happen. I used the library `htmltools`.

```
browsable(div(style = "width:100%;",
              div(style = "width:50%; float: left;", fig1),
              div(style = "width:50%; float: right;", fig2)))
```

[image]